# AWS_EC2 ssh Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, pem

Ugh, so I've read every S.O. solution and nothing has worked.

Long story short, apple reformatted my computer and I lost my Private key to ssh into my aws ec2 linux instance. I generated a new key, changed the permissions to 400 and tried to ssh but I'm getting:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

when i use the -v option I'm seeing:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname [path-to-my-new-pem]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

any ideas?

Comment: Show your entire command.

Comment: How did you get the new keypair onto the ec2 instance?

Comment: AWS EC2 key, if lost, is irreplaceable! You cannot access that instance again.

Comment: show your command. it's pretty clear what the problem is, but it's hard to tell you how to correct it without the command.

Comment: you need to change the associated key-pair of the ec2 instance, can you confirm you did that ?

Comment: Here is the full command: ssh -i ~/.ssh/[new-pem-key] ec2-user@[instance-ip]

Comment: I created a new key pair for the area. I'm not sure I associated it with the correct instance. is their documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

when you say that you generated a new key, you still need to import the key pair into the EC2 instance, which obviously you cannot since you lost the current private key. ok so how to move it from there.

**You need the key pair to be uploaded into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys**

The procedure is explained in amazon doc [Connecting to Your Linux Instance if You Lose Your Private Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair)

basically you need to:

- create a new key pair from AWS console
- Stop your current instance (do not `terminate` as you would loose the current data)
- detach the current Volume V of the instance
- Launch a new instance (* specify the same Availability Zone as the instance you'd like to connect to. If you're launching an instance in a VPC, select a subnet in this Availability Zone.*)
- Attach the volume V to the new instance

--> now you have access to all your data, update the `authorized_keys` with the new key pair

- detach again the volume V from the new instance and attach it back to the old instance
- start the new instance
- ssh with the new key pair

Comment: Awesome! I was able use the volume of the server I was locked out to the server of a new instance. I'm just confused on the step : "now you have access to all your data, update the authorized_keys with the new key pair"

Comment: once you mount to a new partition the volume (something like `sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt/tempvol`) you can browse the `/mnt/tempvol` which is the content of your drive, so `mnt/tempvol/home/<ec2-user>/.ssh/` is the folder you are interested and you can update the `authorized_keys` with the new key you generated